# is there a better way of concatenating date type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have Date Type colum with data looking like this:

```
2011-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

And i want to recive from that something like

```
2011-7-1
```

there is my way, but probably could be done better

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(ModifiedDate) AS varchar(15)) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(ModifiedDate) AS varchar(15)) + '-' + CAST(DAY(ModifiedDate) AS varchar(15))
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? From 2012 onwards, [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) is available, which makes this (almost) trivial.

Comment: do you have to have hypens? this will be slashes

SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)

Comment: I'm working on 2014, thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Cast to `date` instead of trying to manipulate **localized** strings. Why create a string when you want a *date* ?

Comment: Why not leave it to the client to do the formating in whatever way it sees fit? Just return the date type directly.

Comment: I agree this belongs at the application level. Let the database return the correct datatype and application can do what it wants with it.

Answer (score 1):

per comment feed back and reference: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

This CAST is ANSI standard vs CONVERT

```
SELECT CAST(GetDate() as DATE)
```

why not to use FORMAT and should generally be left for the UI to do

why not to use CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @variable, 101)

[image]

Comment: Why convert to a *localized string* and then parse it back to a date instead of simply casting the `datetime` to a `date` ? The double conversion will fail if the user modifies the `DATEFORMAT` setting

Comment: i adjusted what the from comments

Comment: That returns '2011-07-01'.  Not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @paparazzo "there is my way, but probably could be done better", keeping date datatype is a huge performance plus, so having a 0 I amm sure is not so important to him as he is asking for advice. Guess nobody is getting cookies here

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik Again the select does little to effect performance.  They can still operation on datetime in where and joins.  You are sure format is not important to him?

Comment: yes little effect on performance on one select, how about 1 million, how about after the where clause, how about a join?  table scan, are your locking?, your RDMS will be waiting.... a while

Answer (score -1):

You can use `FORMAT`, `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

This will return you the datepart formatted for different cultures:

```
DECLARE @ft DATETIME = '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT FORMAT(@FT, 'd', 'en-us')
```

RESULT: `7/11/2011`

```
DECLARE @ft DATETIME = '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT FORMAT(@ft, 'yyyy-M-d')
```

RESULT: `2011-7-11`

More about FORMAT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

This will return you the datepart:

```
DECLARE @ft DATETIME = '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT CAST(@FT as date)
```

RESULT: `2011-07-11`

This gives you more options for different formatting:

```
DECLARE @ft DATETIME = '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ft, 101)
```

RESULT: `2011-07-01`

Instead of variable, you can use text too:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000', 101)
```

RESULT: `2011-07-01`

More about CAST and CONVERT :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Why use localized string manipulation when the OP asks how to generate a *date* from a *datetime*? Just cast to `date`. It's not nitpicking. In a `WHERE` statement string manipulation will result in a full table scan even if there are indexes. SQL Server though recognizes `cast(somedatetime as date)` and replaces it with a range search that can take advantage of indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the OP asks how to get '2011-7-1' from a datetime, and above are several options. OP can select whatever to use. And, there is an option with 'CAST (`SELECT CAST(@FT as date)`)

Comment: Only one of those options returns  '2011-7-1'

Answer (score -1):

You can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to do this.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT FORMAT(@DATE, 'yyyy-M-d')
Result: 2011-7-1
```